# Fórmula Excel para procurar parte do texto em uma tabela

Tags: microsoft-excel, algoritmo-de-busca, referência, fórmula, procv

Tenho uma tabela de bancos e códigos em duas colunas.

Ex.:

Banco do brasil S/A  001

Banco do Estado do Rio Grande do Sul - Banrisul         041

Banco Santander do Brasil  033

Banco Mercantil do Brasil  208

Banco Itaú S/A       341

Algumas expressões se repetem como "Brasil", "Banco", "S/A". Então tenho que procurar por termos específicos.
Às vezes, o termo específico está no meio do nome, como "Rio Grande" ou "Mercantil".

Eu só consigo usar "PROCV" se eu souber a sequência exata deesde o início do nome, e ainda corro o risco de localizar outro banco com a mesma expressão.
Se eu sei que em algum ponto da coluna existe um banco que possui "Rio Grande" no nome, mas não sei como está escrito o restante do nome, como faço para procurar em uma coluna inteira uma expressão dentro do um texto de cada célula da coluna?

Comment: Não consegue procurar pelo código?

Comment: É uma planilha de preenchimento de diversos dados.

Comment: Um deles é o cód. do banco. mas tive que criar uma tela lateral onde o usuário possa procurar o código pelo nome do banco, caso não saiba o código de cor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o `PROCV` com asteríscos. Supondo que o campo digitado se encontra na célula A1 e a sua tabela de bancos e códigos está no intervalo A4:B50, por exemplo, a fórmula ficaria assim:

```
=PROCV("*"&A1&"*";A4:B50;2;FALSO)
```

[image: Resultado (meu Excel está em inglês)]

Comment: Não conhecia o recurso dos asteriscos. Obrigadaço!